# Alpha and Omega

Tags: riddle, word

I am the beginning of everything,
the end of time and space,
the beginning of every end,
and the end of every place.

What am I?

Comment: A similar riddle like this went viral on twitter last month. :)

Comment: Oh really? I wans't aware of that. Maybe you guys were so fast solving thix :)

Comment: hmmm "black hole"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> The letter E

Because:

> Everything begins with E
>  Time and space end with E
>  End begins with E
>  Place ends with E

Comment: That's the correct answer :)